# Automatically clean Boot Partition once a day/once a week

Tags: scripting, kernel, boot, apt, partition

Our company is providing customers with a digital signage Kiosk Machine that is running Customized Ubuntu 20.04. We had cases where some of the Kiosk Machines had a full boot partition. We had to manually clean the partition. We are now searching for a way to do this with a script that runs once a week.

Better would be to completely disable the download of newer kernel versions. Disabling apt updates should normally stop kernels from being downloaded, right?

Thanks in advance for the Help, and please tell me where I can improve my question.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels https://askubuntu.com/questions/590673/why-doesnt-ubuntu-remove-old-kernels-automatically

Comment: Ubuntu normally only keeps 2 kernels. current and one older just in case issue with newer. Is /boot too small? Also check settings on keeping kernels in `cat /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal`